# Md-dialog usage in angular

Tags: angularjs, material-design

I have an md-dialog in my main html and my controller code is like below.

```
var dialogAppCtrl = function($scope,$mdDialog){
        $scope.openDialog = function(ev){
            $mdDialog.show({
                controller:'dialogCtrl',
                scope: $scope,
                preserveScope: true,
                parent: angular.element(document.body),
                targetEvent: ev,
                clickOutsideToClose: false,
                templateUrl: 'dialog.tmpl.html',
            })
        }
    };
```

I purposefully made clickOutsideToClose false. I actually want a method to be called when user clicks on the outside.

Is there any way i can accomplish it ?

demo on jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/e5j1p6mo/

Here I am setting the closable to true on  the click of the button and its working fine, but still the dialog is not getting closed?

Comment: So do you want this method to get called every time someone closes the dialog or only if he/she tries to closes it when it clicks only outside (not any possible cancel button)

Comment: @VassilisPits yes when user clicks on outside I need to do some checks before closing the dialog

Comment: yes I asked you if that includes the cancel button though.

Comment: @VassilisPits no cancel button when user clicks on the outside

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it like this:

1st in your `dialogCtrl` you should add a close function and pass a parameter in the `cancel` method in order to catch it later like this:

```
$scope.close = function() {
    $mdDialog.cancel('button');
}
```

Then in your template `dialog.tmpl.html` call it with your cancel/close button like this:

```
<md-button class="md-raised" ng-click="dialogCtrl.close()">Cancel</md-button>
```

or depending your code:

```
<md-button class="md-raised" ng-click="close()">Cancel</md-button>
```

Finally alter your code that calls your dialog to this:

```
var dialogAppCtrl = function ($scope, $mdDialog) {
    $scope.openDialog = function (ev) {
        $mdDialog.show({
                controller: 'dialogCtrl',
                scope: $scope,
                preserveScope: true,
                parent: angular.element(document.body),
                targetEvent: ev,
                clickOutsideToClose: false,
                templateUrl: 'dialog.tmpl.html',
            })
            .then(function () {
                    // Success code here
                },
                function (e) {
                    if (e === 'button') {
                       // Cancel button was clicked
                    } else {
                       // Outside was clicked, do your stuff here
                    }
                })
    }
};
```

As you can see dialog is still closing (there is no event from this unfortunately) BUT you can handle the event as you wish now.

Comment: I dont have a button to close the dialog only way is to click outside

Comment: It still works then. I gave you an option to execute the code you want in the `// Outside was clicked` area. You can remove the `if else` then and still it is going to work.

Comment: I have added a jsfiddle demo can you please check that